# What is the scope of Javascript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: Broken Scope]

Could someone explain to me how the above is generating warnings.

It should be noted before being asked, the $me variable is not defined outside of the function call. Surely the scope of $me should end at the end of the "if" statement.

I feel that I am missing something glaringly obvious here, but can't quite put my finger on it.

Comment: Scopes only end within functions. `$me` does not disappear just because you go out of the `if` query (if it did, what the heck are you doing with your code?!). Simply declare `var $me` outside.

Comment: http://diablo.incgamers.com/gallery/data/500/cannot-be-unseen.jpg

Comment: In javascript "blocks don't create scope". Whether you declare a variable in a for-loop, if-statement or while/do while loop, that variable will exist outside that block.

Comment: hmm well thats different to every languageI have used in the past. Defining a variable inside an if statement in C# / VB.net you cannot access it outside the if statement.

Comment: @h2ooooooo I have cut out unrelevant code so as only the part I believed to be causing the problem remains ;)

Comment: @M.S If you thought that, what *are* you trying to do with this code?! **Edit**: Have you thought about a loop instead of `n` similar if statements?

Comment: Its not an issue, as stated, the code still works, I just wanted to understand the error of my ways so it could be rectified, defining the variable global to the function then reassigning has the exact same effect but removes all the warnings ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JavaScript variables are not limited to block scope.

```
var foo = "a";
if (true) {
    var foo = "b";
}
console.log(foo); // "b" not "a"
```

Variable declarations get hoisted (moved to the top), so really this says:

```
var foo;
var foo;
foo = "a"
if (true) {
    foo = "b";
}
console.log(foo); // "b"
```

Variables always get hoisted to the top of the scope. In general only functions have scope. `if` doesn't create it's own scope. Neither does `for`, `while` or even `switch`.

It's *easy* to make this mistake (even for veteran programmers) so JSHint lets you know about it.

Comment: Thumbs up for mentioning hoisting

Comment: use `if(false)` to make it more impressive

Comment: @jAndy that doesn't actually work. Just the declaration gets hoisted, not the definition ;) - It's important to realize that `var foo = "bar"` is a declaration _and_ a definition and they are two _separate_ things.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen I think Andys point was that it'd still get hoisted even though it would **never ever** get to where it should declare it (if they weren't hoisted). The problem is that the compiler probably doesn't realize that it never enters the condition until it's already too late (runtime compiling).

Comment: Just to clarify, if you substitute for `false` it will give `"a"`, not `"b"`, because `foo` is never redefined. JSHint will still give you the warning (and rightfully so).

Comment: @FritsvanCampen Yes, but `var foo; if (false) { var foo; }` *shouldn't* get hoisted to `var foo, foo` as the condition will *never* be true. That's the point that makes it more "impressive".

Comment: Why shouldn't it get hoisted? If your compiler is smart enough to optimize (ie. remove) the `if(false)` part the hoisting becomes moot. I don't want to go into compiler optimization here, take the example as-is, don't think too much about it. Read it as `if(bool)` if you will.

Answer (score 4):

`if` statements doesn't have own scope. It's still scope in which there were used, eg. function or global scope.

Because of that, variables defined in `if` will collide with previous defined variables.

Comment: The variables declarations *will* collide because of hoisting, regardless of whether that part of the code is ever reached.

Comment: "can collide" is not the same as "will collide".

Comment: @Juhana `Can collide` instead of `will collide` because it can have different names :) But I'll edit to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

The function repeatedly attempts to declare `var $me` when it should only be declared once.

```
//Scope is defined at function level
function something(){
    var $me = {}; //declaration, only do this once within a function
    if(something){
       $me = "x"; //assignment, for after a var is declared
    }else if(somethingElse){
       $me = "y";  //another assignment, do this as much as you want
    }
}
```